# How to spawn items from command blocks with special names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried so many things to get this to work
so: I'm trying to make this Minecraft map where one of the objectives is to collect a bunch of a renamed item, specifically raw gold, I want to rename them Starpieces.

Now I know you can summon non-named items just fine, I have a tree that drops bread when you press the button for it. I'm sure there is a collection of NBT tags that can rename the raw gold to Starpieces (and the bread to something else) but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work.

Again, I'm trying to summon 1 raw gold, at specific coordinates that's been renamed to Starpiece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomName` tag is shown in *death messages* and *villager trading interface*. By renaming raw gold on anvil and viewing its entitydata, I've noticed `tag` NBT-tag inside the `Item`.

[image: 1]

Exactly this one appears at the player's inventory, therefore the final command is:

`/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item: {id: "minecraft:raw_gold", Count: 1, tag: {display: {Name: '{"text":"Starpiece"}'}}}}`

Comment: thank you so very much, the wording on the minecraft wiki is just confusing and I just couldn't get it to happen, the closest I had gotten was to spawn the unnamed raw gold.

I have saved this command for future use, and again thank you very much

Comment: Very good observations! I commend you for taking this path to find out the right answer. Good job! For more information, `CustomName` is a tag used for *entities*, whereas `display.Name` is a tag used for *items*.